# strcpy() error in Visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

so I have this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
```

...

```
char* b = new char [10];
strcpy(b, "1234567890");
```

error: microsoft visual studio 11.0\vc\include\string.h(110) : see declaration of 'strcpy'

How do I fix it?

Comment: Is that the full error message?  Are you sure that there isn't more to it, perhaps complaining that you should avoid using `strcpy`?

Comment: error C4996: 'strcpy': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using strcpy_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

Comment: The simplest way around this is to Define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS in your compilers preprocessor settings. Or if you want use the nonstandard strcpy_s which takes a size parameter after each argument to strcpy.

Comment: For gcc 4.6 it's ok. I think the same as @John.

Comment: The funny thing is that here, it is actually saving your butt because you copy 11 characters into a 10-character array. Really, use `std::string` instead.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There's an explanation and solution for this on MSDN:

> The function strcpy is considered unsafe due to the fact that there is
>   no bounds checking and can lead to buffer overflow.
>
> Consequently, as it suggests in the error description, you can use
>   strcpy_s instead of strcpy:
>
> strcpy_s(    char *strDestination,    size_t numberOfElements,
>   const char *strSource  );

and:

> To disable deprecation, use
>   _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for details.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/da-DK/vcgeneral/thread/c7489eef-b391-4faa-bf77-b824e9e8f7d2

Comment: Disabling the insecure function warnings isn't exactly a (good) solution; using the secure versions is a much better idea. That goes double in this case, where the example code *will cause a buffer overrun*.

Comment: I agree completely.  However, when you're porting code you might not want to chase down every strcpy and make it a strcpy_s/strncpy/whatever so it's nice to know both options :)

Answer (score 23):

A quick fix is to add the _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS definition to your project's settings

Right-click your C++ and chose the "Properties" item to get to the properties window.

Now follow and expand to, "Configuration Properties"->"C/C++"->"Preprocessor"->"Preprocessor definitions".

In the "Preprocessor definitions" add

> _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

but it would be a good idea to add

> _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS;%(PreprocessorDefinitions)

as to inherit predefined definitions

IMHO & for the most part this is a good approach.

Answer (score 6):

Add this line top of the header

```
#pragma warning(disable : 4996)
```

Answer (score 5):

The message you are getting is advice from MS that they recommend that you do not use the standard strcpy function. Their motivation in this is that it is easy to misuse in bad ways (and the compiler generally can't detect and warn you about such misuse). In your post, you are doing exactly that. You can get rid of the message by telling the compiler to not give you that advice. The serious error in your code would remain, however.

You are creating a buffer with room for 10 chars. You are then stuffing 11 chars into it. (Remember the terminating '\0'?) You have taken a box with exactly enough room for 10 eggs and tried to jam 11 eggs into it. What does that get you? Not doing this is your responsibility and the compiler will generally not detect such things.

You have tagged this C++ and included string. I do not know your motivation for using strcpy, but if you use std::string instead of C style strings, you will get boxes that expand to accommodate what you stuff in them.

Answer (score 3):

I had to use strcpy_s and it worked.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

struct student
{
    char name[30];
    int age;
};

int main()
{

    struct student s1;
    char myname[30] = "John";
    strcpy_s (s1.name, strlen(myname) + 1 ,myname );
    s1.age = 21;

    cout << " Name: " << s1.name << " age: " << s1.age << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The fact it worked does not mean it's correct - you passed the exact value that is not supposed to be passed (ie. size of the data vs size of the destination buffer) : http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcpy

Comment: @RnR so what is the magical correct value that need to be passed. No need for explanation, just need to know what to type

Comment: @mnr I'd suggest to follow the suggestion: "destsz - maximum number of characters to write, typically the size of the destination buffer" so in this case the magical number would be just sizeof(s1.name) or even 30 - both avoiding the strlen call. Strlen is bad because you will still have a buffer overrun if the copied value is longer than the destination buffer.

Comment: Ps. preferably some constant like student.MAX_NAME_LEN would be best for both the call to copy_s and the declarations of the arrays (sizeof (array/pointer) is not that clear IMHO)

Answer (score 0):

If you are getting an error saying something about deprecated functions, try doing `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS` or `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE`. These should fix it. You can also use Microsoft's "secure" functions, if you want.

Answer (score -3):

For my problem, I removed the  `#include <glui.h>` statement and it ran without a problem.

Comment: Useless answer.  `glui.h` isn't a header seen in the original problem.