# How to deal with string input which was allocated?

Tags: c, string

I was writing a function, which concatenates strings when I found a problem in its second argument.
Here is simplified version of my function

```
struct c_class* _Append_s(void* self, const char* str,const DWord length) // DWord is unsigned int
{
    struct c_class* this = self;

    this->inStr = realloc(this->inStr, length + this->len);
#pragma warning(disable:4996)
    strcpy(this->inStr + this->len, str);  // MSVC does an annoying warnings C4996
#pragma warning(default:4996)
    this->len += length;

    return this;
}
```

this function takes `struct c_class*` as an input argument (`void* self`), a `string` to append and its `length` in bytes and returns struct pointer(it's made to make consecutive calls)
struct c_class itself contains a char* inStr and length of string. But that's not the case.

As an input _Append_s may take regular const strings`char* in = "some text"`, char arrays - `char in[10]` but also an allocated strings `char* inm = malloc(n)`.

**So the questions are:**

1) can I somehow track which strings are allocated and free them upon concatenation? Better it would be without additional input, because it's an internal function and I call it from wrappers of types int and char*.

2) maybe there is a way to transform allocated string to a const string expression and free memory afterwards?

If the second thing is possible, the first question becomes obsolete, because it solves a problem where I need to yield a finished string and free a memory, which `struct c_class*` occupies

Comment: Which String do you want to free after concatenation?

Comment: @Ahrtaler input one

Comment: Is that `str` in your example?

Comment: @Ahrtaler yes it is

Answer (score 0):

If you want to free the char array you only have to add `free((char*)str);` above `return this;` But maybe I didn't understand you right.

As John Humphreys - w00te pointed out in this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12204279/6911200 the warning C4996 means:

> The function strcpy is considered unsafe due to the fact that there is no bounds checking and can lead to buffer overflow.
>
> Consequently, as it suggests in the error description, you can use `strcpy_s` instead of `strcpy`:
>
> ```
> strcpy_s( char *strDestination, size_t numberOfElements,
> const char *strSource );
> ```

Comment: The thing is, if you free a const string, will it not produce errors? Because the place it's allocated at is different

Comment: No there should not be an error, if you convert it into a non const array. like I did with `(char*)str`. The place wher you allocate memory is not important. You can free memory where you want, if you know the pointer.

Comment: ok, I'll try it. strcpy_s doesn't work for some reason, it writes a lot of errors, what to paste as numberOfElements there? And the safety features are not required since it has length and and it can't exceed the memory given by realloc

Comment: `strcpy_s` works as following: `strcpy_s(destination, sizeof destination, source)`. It retruns 0 if it was succesfull. `destination` is the pointer, where you want to copy the string, `sizeof destination` is the length of your array. Use the `sizeof` keyword for that. `source` is the pointer of the string, you want to coppy.

Comment: notice that strcopy in my case does not simply copy string, it overwrites a content past its `len`, so buffer size is not equal to result size, and `sizeof(dest) `will just return 8 because it's a pointer on x64 machine. And also `free` does not work with const strings, I tried and it failed on checking heap

Comment: Can you please give a example how you used `free`?

Comment: ```private.len += length;

 free((char*)str);

 return this;``` inside _Append_s

Comment: I tried a bit and I found, that it is only possible to use free, if you used malloc, or realloc to allocate the memory. If you write `char str1[15];` or something equal, free does not work. And ofcourse you are right about `sizeof(dest)` things. I didn't thought about that.